# 可変長テンプレートの展開と引数の評価順序についての疑問。

Tags: c++

```
class my_vector
    : private std::vector<int>
{
    template <std::size_t... Index>
    void func_1_(std::index_sequence<Index...>)
    {
        int n[] = { 0, (static_cast<void>(push_back(Index)), 0)... };
    }
    template <std::size_t... Index>
    void func_2_(std::index_sequence<Index...>)
    {
        [](auto&&...){}((static_cast<void>(push_back(Index)), 0)...);
    }
public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    void func_1()
    {
        func_1_(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    }
    template <std::size_t N>
    void func_2()
    {
        func_2_(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    }

    using std::vector<int>::begin;
    using std::vector<int>::end;
    using std::vector<int>::clear;
};
```

```
int main()
{
    my_vector v;
    for(auto& i : v)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    v.func_1<10>();
    for(auto& i : v)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v.clear();
    for(auto& i : v)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    v.func_2<10>();
    for(auto& i : v)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

このように出力されました。

> 0123456789
>   9876543210

こう出力されると想定していました。

> 0123456789
>   0123456789

どうして2行目の出力がそうなるのか教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
void func_2_(std::index_sequence<Index...>)
{
    [](auto&&...){}((static_cast<void>(push_back(Index)), 0)...);
}
```

このラムダ関数について、ちょっと説明します。

関数の引数がどんな順番で評価 (計算) されるかは、C++ の言語仕様上、未規程です。つまりコンパイラは、好き勝手な順番で引数を評価してもいいのです。有名な問題ですが、

```
int i = 0;
f(++i, ++i, ++i);
```

で、関数 f に渡される引数の値はどうなるでしょうか。答えは、分からない、です。前から評価して (1, 2, 3) になるかもしれない。前置インクリメントなので、最初にまとめて計算して (3, 3, 3) になるかもしれない。同じコンパイラを使っていても、最適化の都合で、毎回違う順番に評価されるかもしれない。

ラムダ関数でも同じで、どんな順番に引数が評価されるかは分かりません。今回のコードでは、10個の コンマ式 `(static_cast<void>(push_back(Index)), 0)` が引数として渡されるわけですが、このコンマ式がどの順番で評価 (= 中の `push_back` がどの順番で実行) されるかは分かりません。まったくでたらめな順番でもいいのです。

ほとんどの処理系では、デフォルトでは引数を後ろからスタックに積みます。おそらく、コンパイラが引数をスタックに一つずつ積む毎に評価したので、順番が逆転したのでしょう。

Comment: +1: 重箱の隅つつきですが関数引数の評価順は「未定義(undefined)」ではなく「未規程(unspecified)」となります。（用語だけの問題で、あとは回答に書かれている通りですね）

Comment: @yohjp ご指摘、ありがとうございます。編集しておきます。