# C++の入門書は読んだのですがfor文の書き方を知りません

Tags: c++, c++11

[可変長テンプレートの展開と引数の評価順序についての疑問。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14699/%E5%8F%AF%E5%A4%89%E9%95%B7%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%B1%95%E9%96%8B%E3%81%A8%E5%BC%95%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E8%A9%95%E4%BE%A1%E9%A0%86%E5%BA%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E7%96%91%E5%95%8F)
上の質問で

```
 for(auto& i : v)
```

といった書き方を見たのですが、

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

のような書き方しか知りません。上の書き方はどのような入門書または、中級上級まとめて専門書を読んだらいいのですか
それと、コンパイラにオプションとかは必要になりますか

Comment: 使っているコンパイラとバージョンを書かれるといいかと思います。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

新しい規格[C++11](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)で導入された書き方です。
書籍では、「[プログラミング言語C++第4版](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4797375957)」や「[改訂新版 C++ポケットリファレンス](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4774174084)」がC++11に対応していますが、前者は非常に高価な書籍です。
Webでは、「["C++11" 範囲for](https://www.google.co.jp/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22C%2B%2B11%22+%E7%AF%84%E5%9B%B2for)」や「["C++11" auto](https://www.google.co.jp/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22C%2B%2B11%22+auto)」等で検索すればヒットします。

GCCやClangの場合は、バージョンによってはオプションとして「-std=c++11」の指定が必要です。
Visual C++の場合は、オプションの指定は不要ですが、「[コンパイラの実装状況](http://cpprefjp.github.io/implementation-status.html)」等を参考にしてC++11の範囲forとautoに対応したバージョンをお使いください。

Comment: Effective Modern C++ ―C++11/14プログラムを進化させる42項目2015/9/25
Scott Meyers、 　と　千住 治郎、C＋＋11/14 コア言語2015/9/25
江添 亮　が来月のC++11というのにあてはまりそうです。

Comment: @user11041 江添氏の参考書は、[Webで読む](https://github.com/EzoeRyou/cpp-book)こともできます。

Answer (score 4):

C++11で導入されたようです。なので古いC++の入門書には無いと思います。

参照URL
http://minus9d.hatenablog.com/entry/20130815/1376557665

Comment: もしかして、ウェブページで勉強する他ないわけですか

Comment: @user11041 C++11について現在書籍化されているものはポケットリファレンスだけだと思います。電子媒体は分かりませんが、紙媒体で2冊来月刊行される見込みですが、入門書という形だと難しいと思います。

Comment: リファレンスと言うことでよければ、ビャーネ・ストラウストラップ著、プログラミング言語C++第4版がありますが、なにしろ高いです。